# About Mechanism of Memory Release in Boehm GC

Tags: c, memory, operating-system, boehm-gc

I am studying the workings of Boehm GC (Garbage Collector). One aspect I am trying to understand is the specific operations that occur on the computer when Boehm GC releases memory.

How does the C language runtime library, specifically, understand that a particular memory region is not in use? Additionally, is it necessary for the OS to make changes to Page Table Entries (PTE) or Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB) when freeing memory?

Comment: I don't know the details of Boehm GC but perhaps you can find some useful information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Precise_vs._conservative_and_internal_pointers and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector

Comment: GC operates on user mode memory, it has nothing to do with the internals of the VM implementation. It's basically just a replacement for the `malloc/realloc/free` functions.

Comment: It's just automatically calling `free()` when it detects that some allocated memory is no longer reachable.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for [cs.se].